# ¿Se puede usar el estado para activar transiciones/animaciones en React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Muchachos, tengo una duda poderosa.

En React, tengo entendido que el uso del estado está reservado para los datos que cambian con el tiempo.

¿Es válido usar el estado para cambiar la posición o display de un elemento hijo, animar otros o activar transiciones? Es decir, ¿puedo usar el estado para agregar interactividad, y no solamente para guardar el modelo de datos externo y mutarlo?

Tengo la duda principalmente porque me confunde que la documentación de React diga que para activar animaciones imperativas es mejor utilizar referencias, amén de que mutar el estado ocasiona nuevos renderizados y no sé si es costoso para React tener que re-renderizar un componente solo porque se activó una transición.

Comment: Efectivamente, es mejor dejar las transiciones fuera del estado, ya que puede ser muy complicado manejar cada evento de la misma (cuándo inicia, cuándo termina) para cambiar el estado. Un ejemplo de un componente (muy útil) que maneja transiciones animadas para que tú no lo hagas es [react-router](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/animated-transitions).

Answer (score 1):

Si puedes agregar interactividad mediante el estado recuerda que este es un objeto , y en su estado inicial puedes declarar como va a inicializarse el componente en el primer render , y luego actualizar este estado mediante un método  o una función sea el caso que estés usando *clases* o *funciones* **"Hooks"** ,con *clases* mediante **setState** o con *hooks* usando **useState** con respecto a re-renderizados innecesarios es un tema bastante amplio e influyen muchos factores como mencione anteriormente si usas *clases* o *hooks* , otra es como implementas tu código y como utilizas los ciclos de vida del mismo ya que esto varia según uses *clases* o *hooks* , usar referencias depende de lo mismo.
Todo se reduce a cómo **React** funciona tras bastidores. **React** promete que es muy rápido al representar elementos en una página. Para ello mantiene en memoria dos versiones del DOM (*Document Object Model*):

La versión del **DOM** actualmente mostrada.
La próxima versión del **DOM** que se mostrará.
Compara los dos y actualiza el **DOM** visualizado con solo las partes que han cambiado. Este proceso se llama** reconciliación**. La raíz del árbol evaluado para la reconciliación es un componente cuyos props han cambiado.

Entonces, tenemos 2 versiones del dom durante la evaluación de componentes en **React**, podemos aprovechar estas 2 versiones con el método **shouldComponentUpdate().**

Este método en español significa (Literal) **DeberiaEsteComponenteActualizarse()** y su razón de existir es el de evaluar los props actuales con los props futuros y el *state* actual con el *state* futuro.
Esta estrategia busca evitar re renders innecesarios, que pueden provocar *lag* para la interfaz de usuario esto si usas clases ya que es un método de ciclo de vida de estas en el caso de **hooks** como te dice la documentación puedes usar referencias mediante useRef se usa para crear un objeto mutable y las propiedades de un objeto mutable se pueden cambiar a voluntad sin afectar el estado de un componente. aqui te dejo un enlace que puede darte una mejor idea con respecto al rendimiento: https://medium.com/noders/sobre-observables-performance-y-magia-negra-en-react-con-context-y-hooks-dae3e407f7a0
espero te sirva la info.

Comment: pero estoy totalmente deacuerdo con respecto a dejar las transiciones fuera del estado puede resultar bastante confuso y complicarse un monton , mi respuesta anterior la formule en base a que si puedes hacerlo mediante el estado , no que manera seria mas practica y comoda  :)